# In Magento how to show custom attribute in product grid ..?

Tags: magento

Thanks in advance

i have made one attribute with option of yes/no i want to show this in product grid at admin side i made the column in the grid and put the following code

```
<?php
$this->addColumn('approvedcustomer',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('UrgeStatus'),
                'index' => 'approvedcustomer',
        ));

?>
```

here approvedcustomer is attribute and it contains option yes/no 
but in grid it shows 0 and 1 how can i show Approved and Unapproved insted of 0 and 1..

sorry for my english,

thanks once again.

Jeet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should assign "**options**" type for your column.

```
$this->addColumn('approvedcustomer',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('UrgeStatus'),
        'index' => 'approvedcustomer',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => array(
            0 => 'No',
            1 => 'Yes',
        )
));
```